# How to get Facebook User details in tvOS

Tags: facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0, tvos, apple-tv

i am using Facebook SDK in **tvOS** for **Login**. Currently i have used below code.

```
FBSDKDeviceLoginButton *button = [[FBSDKDeviceLoginButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
button.readPermissions = @[@"email"];
button.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

first m confused at which Action can i use `readPermissions = @[@"email"];` or `publishPermissions = @[@"publish_actions"];`
and then How to get user details like *firstName, lastName, email, Birth date*, and *Id* from facebook Responce

Comment: I've been looking into this couldnt find anything yet, looking for doc but there is not doc available yet. any luck ? please update

Answer (score 0):

Getting details of the user can be accomplished by connecting to our [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph) once you have a valid token. For example, after a success login to get first name and last name:

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
   [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=first_name,last_name" parameters:nil]
    startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
      if (!error) {
         NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
      }
  }];
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit more like how can we get email id, profile picture, gender @Chris Pan and what is the logic behind this way around like in mobile sdk when we can fetch data easily so why in tvOS we have to do it through this way

Answer (score 0):

It is not same as mobile-sdk you should try graph api like how @chrispan is suggesting i've tried that & it is working perfectly. Just add as many fields you want in parameters and you'll get all the data which is set to public by user.

```
        FBSDKGraphRequest.init(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields" : "email, gender, name, birthday"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (
            FBSDKGraphRequestConnection connection, id result, let error: NSError? ) -> Void in

            if(error == nil)
            {
                print("fetched user: %@", result)

            }

        })
```

Now, your question about permission. When user is signing up(first time) at that particular point you ask for "Read permission" and "Publish permission" is used when you want to post something to his/her timeline.